# Can't upload image with the rest of the inputted data

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I'm pretty new to CodeIgniter so I can only utilize certain aspects of what the framework can offer. In this case I wanted to enable the user to upload an image with the rest of their information. I tried sort of combining logic from what I've created with tutorials and information I've found here to no avail. With how this code currently is it will upload all the information to the server but it will not upload anything to do with the image the user entered. So, I assume I'm doing something fatally wrong. Any advice is appreciated.

```
    function adduser(){
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_width'] = '1024';
        $config['max_height'] = '1024';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $uinfo = $this->upload->data();
        $file = array(
            'img_name' => $uinfo['raw_name'],
            'ext' => $uinfo['file_ext']
        );
        $fullfile = $file['img_name'].$file['file_ext'];

        $data = array(
            'userid' => $this->session->userdata('userid'),
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'year' => $this->input->post('year'),
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'image' => $fullfile
        );
        $this->db->insert('user', $data);
        redirect('user/index');
}
```

Comment: Use CI's error reporting https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html if you're not doing so already, and see if anything comes of it.

Comment: @thelonelydoge You missed upload process of codeigniter. Should use `$this->upload->do_upload()`. For more check [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try the following

```
public function adduser(){
    {
             //This is the directory to which we upload our image
             //full permission is required for this folder
             //FCPATH is a constant defined in index.php - its the relative path to project root
             $config['upload_path']    = FCPATH.'uploads/';
             //Validation - Only gif jpg png extensions are allowed
             $config['allowed_types']  = 'gif|jpg|png';
             //unique file name
             $file_name           = time();
             $config['file_name'] = $file_name;
             $config['max_width'] = '1024';
             $config['max_height'] = '1024';

             $this->load->library('upload', $config);
             //checking file upload success

             if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image')) //here image is your file input name
             {
                //error in file uploading
                $message = $this->upload->display_errors();
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($message);
                exit;
             }
             else
             {
                //successfully uploaded the image
                $message = 'file uploaded successfully';
                //getting full file upload information
                $result  = $this->upload->data();
                $data = array(
                    'userid' => $this->session->userdata('userid'),
                    'name'  => $this->input->post('name'),
                    'year'  => $this->input->post('year'),
                    'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                    'image' => $result['file_name']
                );
                $this->db->insert('user', $data);

             }

            redirect('user/index');
    }
```

in the above i have used "image" as file input field name

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. Now I can move on to the delete function for the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try This

     function adduser(){
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_width'] = '1024';
            $config['max_height'] = '1024';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('inputname')) {
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            } else {
                $uinfo = $this->upload->data();
                $file = array(
                    'img_name' => $uinfo['raw_name'],
                    'ext' => $uinfo['file_ext']
                );
                $fullfile = $file['img_name'].$file['file_ext'];

                $data = array(
                    'userid' => $this->session->userdata('userid'),
                    'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                    'year' => $this->input->post('year'),
                    'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                    'image' => $fullfile
                );
                $this->db->insert('user', $data);
                redirect('user/index');
            }
    }

Note: "inputname" is your HTML input file tag
```